# Wepack error : Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

After creating a new component and using it in my Main component and running webpack i get the error

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Here's my code snippet:

```
var React = require('react');
var Nav = require('Nav');

var Main = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    return (
      <Nav />
      <h2>Main Component</h2>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When there are multiple elements, you need to wrap it so it's only returning one:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <h2>Main Component</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: You can't return

```
(
  <Nav />
  <h2>Main Component</h2>
)
```

because they are two components. Wrap them up in something else before returning it.

Comment: Thanks. For explaining why I can’t return components like that. 

Answer (score 0):

It Should be wrapped by a root Element

```
   <div>
     <Nav/>
     <h2>Main Component</h2>
  </div>
```